# In The Matrix Resurrections, is there significance to the name of Christina Ricci's character?

Tags: the-matrix

In the *Matrix* series, character names are often loaded with relevant symbolism. The trend continues in *The Matrix Resurrections*, with names being related to the characters' greater purpose in the story. Gwyn de Vere, an executive at the video game company that Thomas Anderson works at, is a minor character in the film, played by Christina Ricci, who had previously starred in the Wachowskis' *Speed Racer*. I thought nothing of it when I first read it, but [in an interview](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rOqUiXhECos), Keanu Reeves stated that he believes that Edward de Vere, the 17th Earl of Oxford, wrote the plays of William Shakespeare.

Given the themes of identity that are integral to the *Matrix* series, is there any connection between this minor character's name and the greater themes of the movie?

Comment: Haven't seen the movie, but I'd have to say that the immediate association for me is "Guinevere"

Comment: @user888379 I thought that too initially, but if that was the case, I feel like Lana Wachowski would have just named her Guinevere.

Answer (score 1):

[HITC](https://www.hitc.com/en-gb/2021/12/23/christina-ricci-matrix/) speculates that the name may be a reference to Guinevere:

> Many of the names in The Matrix franchise carry connotations, from Neo
> to Morpheus.
>
> Gwyn de Vere’s isn’t explicitly addressed, but one could argue that it
> may be a reference to Guinevere, the queen and wife of King Arthur;
> the names sound strikingly similar, just like Morpheus and Orpheus,
> for example.

[This blog](https://onetakenews.wordpress.com/2021/12/06/christina-ricci-matrix-exclusive/) makes the same connection:

> The name is a play on Guinevere, a character from the Legends of
> Arthur.

I have been unable to find anything official, regarding the character's name.

Comment: In the absence of anything official, guesswork from people who have no connection to the movie is pretty low quality. We might just as easily posit that it's a play on the Welsh for "white feathers" or the Frisian for "made of glass". Does her character even portray any especially Guinevere-like qualities?